# Apache superset error Unexpected Error 'metrics'

Tags: apache-superset

I have run apache superset locally and I still get this error when I embed it in angular
[image]

Looking further at logs, I have seen there are some charts which have parameters named metric while others metrics

[image]

[image]

While on apache superset portal is working properly

[image]

This is the error response I'm getting from the backend

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "'metrics'",
        "error_type": "GENERIC_BACKEND_ERROR",
        "level": "error",
        "extra": {
            "issue_codes": [
                {
                    "code": 1011,
                    "message": "Issue 1011 - Superset encountered an unexpected error."
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}
and for the flask local backend outputs this error

```
superset_app          | 'metrics'
superset_app          | Traceback (most recent call last):
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
superset_app          |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
superset_app          |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators.py", line 87, in wraps
superset_app          |     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/views/base_api.py", line 127, in wraps
superset_app          |     raise ex
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/views/base_api.py", line 121, in wraps
superset_app          |     duration, response = time_function(f, self, *args, **kwargs)
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/utils/core.py", line 1463, in time_function
superset_app          |     response = func(*args, **kwargs)
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/utils/log.py", line 255, in wrapper
superset_app          |     value = f(*args, **kwargs)
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/charts/data/api.py", line 235, in data
superset_app          |     command.validate()
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/commands/chart/data/get_data_command.py", line 68, in validate
superset_app          |     self._query_context.raise_for_access()
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/common/query_context.py", line 137, in raise_for_access
superset_app          |     self._processor.raise_for_access()
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/common/query_context_processor.py", line 754, in raise_for_access
superset_app          |     security_manager.raise_for_access(query_context=self._query_context)
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/security/manager.py", line 1954, in raise_for_access
superset_app          |     or form_data.get("metrics", []) != stored_chart.params_dict["metrics"]
superset_app          | KeyError: 'metrics'
superset_app          | 2024-03-10 02:04:12,548:ERROR:superset.views.base:'metrics'
superset_app          | Traceback (most recent call last):
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
superset_app          |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
superset_app          |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators.py", line 87, in wraps
superset_app          |     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/views/base_api.py", line 127, in wraps
superset_app          |     raise ex
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/views/base_api.py", line 121, in wraps
superset_app          |     duration, response = time_function(f, self, *args, **kwargs)
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/utils/core.py", line 1463, in time_function
superset_app          |     response = func(*args, **kwargs)
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/utils/log.py", line 255, in wrapper
superset_app          |     value = f(*args, **kwargs)
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/charts/data/api.py", line 235, in data
superset_app          |     command.validate()
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/commands/chart/data/get_data_command.py", line 68, in validate
superset_app          |     self._query_context.raise_for_access()
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/common/query_context.py", line 137, in raise_for_access
superset_app          |     self._processor.raise_for_access()
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/common/query_context_processor.py", line 754, in raise_for_access
superset_app          |     security_manager.raise_for_access(query_context=self._query_context)
superset_app          |   File "/app/superset/security/manager.py", line 1954, in raise_for_access
superset_app          |     or form_data.get("metrics", []) != stored_chart.params_dict["metrics"]
superset_app          | KeyError: 'metrics'
```

Anyone with an idea on how this can be sorted ?